# Finding the time complexity of pairing method

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have to write code to take a sorted double array having an odd number of elements, find the pairs of values with the shortest distance between them, and return the remaining value, which is considered as the 'odd one'. Following is the code I've written, and it works and returns the correct value.

Can someone please help me find the time complexity of the algorithm I've used? I tried but it's really confusing.

```
public static Double findPairs(Double[] data, int i, int j, int k, int count) {

    Double oddNumber = -1.;

    if ((k < data.length) && (diff(data[i], data[j]) <= diff(data[j], data[k]))) {
        data[i] = (-1.);
        data[j] = (-1.);
        if (k == data.length - 1) {
            for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
                if (data[c] != -1.) {
                    i = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i != k) {
                for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
                    if ((c > i) && (data[c] != -1.)) {
                        j = c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                findPairs(data, i, j, k, count + 1);                    
            } 
        }
        else {
            for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
                if (data[c] != -1.) {
                    i = c;
                    break;
                }
            }    
            for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
                if ((c > i) && (data[c] != -1.)) {
                    j = c;
                    break;
                }
            }    
            for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
                if ((c > j) && (data[c] != -1.)) {
                    k = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
            findPairs(data, i, j, k, count + 1);
        }
    }
    else if ((k < data.length) && (diff(data[i], data[j]) > diff(data[j], data[k]))) {
        if (k == data.length - 1) {
            data[j] = (-1.);
            data[k] = (-1.);
        }
        else {
            i = j; j = k;
            for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
                if ((c > j) && (data[c] != -1.)) {
                    k = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
            findPairs(data, i, j, k, count);
        }
    }    
    for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
        if (data[c] != -1) {
            oddNumber = data[c];
        }
    }
    return oddNumber;
}
```

Algorithm: You start with the first, second and third element of the array. Compare the differences between the first and second elements and the second and third elements. If the first difference is smaller than or equal to the latter, make the first two elements to (-1). Otherwise, do the same for the second, third and the fourth elements. Continue this process. Whenever the first difference is smaller than the second difference, make the relative elements to (-1) and search from the beginning of the array for elements that are not (-1). Repeat the process starting with the first three elements you find. Whenever the second difference is smaller than the first, keep the first element of the three aside and check with the next three. Do this until you've reached the end of the array.

Comment: (Make sure not to confuse `Double` with `double`, as that can change the performance of your algorithm ***significantly***)

Comment: Could you provide an example of input data and desired result?

Answer (score 1):

The way you've phrased the algorithm and written your code, in the worst case, you can iterate over more and more of the list as the algorithm goes from finding one pair to the next which will be set to -1. So it appears the worst-case running time is O(n^2).

Comment: Thank you very much.I was in a dilemma between O(n^2) and O(n!). Is there a way I could reduce this complexity with only a little adjustment to the code?